# Ensuring that all fields are present in constructor parameter list

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea, dart-analyzer

Is there a standard Dart-way of making sure that all fields of a class are present in a constructor parameter list?

A very simplified example:

```
class Message{
  String header;
  String body;
  DateTime sentAt;

  Message(this.header, this.body, this.sentAt);

  Message makeCopy(){
    return Message(header, body, sentAt);
  }
}
```

Now, a colleague comes along and adds the field `String category`, but forgets to add it to the constructor - and even worse, to the copy constructor. Is there a way to make the IDE (IntelliJ) issue a warning or error about this missing new field?

I'm thinking something similar to the warning issued when omitting an enum value from a  `switch`-statement.

Or is there at least some way to make IntelliJ issue such a warning?

Comment: Probably possible with https://pub.dev/packages/pedantic

Answer (score 1):

You will get warnings or errors if you make your fields `final`, it seems from your class that it would be a good idea anyway.

Now... granted, that only moves that problem to "how do I ensure my colleague makes all new fields final, too".

To do that, you can declare you class `@immutable` and then analyzers can warn you.

Analyzers:

- pub.dev/packages/pedantic
- pub.dev/packages/effective_dart

A possible class declaration:

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

@immutable
class Message {
  final String header;
  final String body;
  final DateTime sentAt;

  const Message(this.header, this.body, this.sentAt);

  Message makeCopy() {
    return Message(header, body, sentAt);
  }
}
```

Try adding a new field or removing one from the constructor, you will get errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way but it is in most cases the correct way to go.

You make all fields `final` and enforce immutability which will lead to a compiler error if the field is not initialized in the constructor.

You can use the dartanalyzer to enforce the following rules or at least generate warnings.
https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_final_fields.html
https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_const_declarations.html

To get started more easily with dartanalyzer you can look at the [pedantic](https://pub.dev/packages/pedantic) package or my preference [lint](https://pub.dev/packages/lint).